# Is it possible to use TensorFlow inside a python script in Azure Machine Learning Studio?

Tags: tensorflow, azure-ml

I'm trying to get TensorFlow running inside a python script in Azure Machine Learning Studio. As TensorFlow is not part of Azure Machine Learning Studio, I needed to import it using a zip file. I followed the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593469/how-can-certain-python-libraries-be-imported-in-azure-mllike-the-line-import-hu

However, when trying to import TensorFlow, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

It seems like TensorFlow is much more than just a python library. It seems like it needs a native library to work. Sounds logically, but there's this video on YouTube showing that it should work after all: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEvoZ6EnUpk

My question is: is it possible to run TensorFlow inside a python script in Azure Machine Learning Studio? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question: yes it is possible. You simple open this example in ML Studio and you'll get a working tensorflow_keras.zip into your workspace: https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/CNN-on-Keras-with-Tensorflow-backend